# rtl attribute in index.html file doesn't work in Angular 10 Project

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I have created an angular 10 project and installed bootstrap4 rtl, but all my components still rendered as ltr.. when i uninstalled bootstrap it worked fine.. do anyone know how to make bootstrap work with rtl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RTL support seems not yet being integrated. There is an open issue on the Bootstrap Github project that you will find [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/30918).

In addition, there exist a [pull request to integrate it](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/30980) in the official project that is actively being updated.

If you want to integrate it right now, I refer you to [RTLCSS](https://rtlcss.com/)'s Bootstrap fork: https://github.com/RTLCSS/bootstrap

Also have a look on their documentation: http://bootstrap.rtlcss.com/

Good luck!